# Advice on how to export data from BQ and load it into Redis

Tags: python, google-bigquery, redis

I am considering the following scenario:

- A certain BQ query must be run on a daily basis, with the data extraction period being given by `CURRENT_DATE()-30 DAYS` and `CURRENT_DATE`. The output table consists of two columns, one labeled `ID` - to be regarded as holding *keys*, of type `INT64` - and another labeled `items`, to be construed as holding *values* of type `RECORD` (or `ARRAY`; on each row the respective `ARRAY` contains precisely 3 elements, each of which is a `STRUCT(INT64, INT64, INT64)`. The image attached right below should help clarify the situation.

[image: format of query output]

- On each daily run of the above specified BQ query, the output must be loaded into Redis by setting the values in `ID` as the keys and the corresponding arrays in `items` as the corresponding values.

Under the main operative assumption that the desired connection between BQ and Redis should be implemented in python, my questions are:

1. What would be the optimal format (method) of exporting the BQ query results? Does one instruct BQ to create a temporary result file in a certain location which one then points Redis to?
2. What exact module does one use in order to feed the BQ query results into Redis? As to the code, is it appropriate to envision a logic loosely delineated as follows?:

```
for row in query_results:
   redis.set(row[key_index], row[value_index])
```

As you can gather, I very much ask this question from the position of a neophyte, so any detailed answer would be more than appreciated. Please feel free to let me know if I should provide more clarity in order to elicit clearer answers!

With anticipating gratitude to all those who have taken the time to parse this question!